# Magento Error : Can't retrieve entity config:

Tags: php, magento

1. I want to create a model for a DB table called "contactform_contact_list"
2. NameSpace is 'Chandan', ModuleName : 'Contactform'
3. So, my app/code/local/Chandan/Contactform/etc/config.xml is like this :

like this:

```
<models>
 <contactform>
   <class>Chandan_Contactform_Model</class> 
   <resourceModel>contactform_resource</resourceModel>
 </contactform>
 <contactform_resource>
  <class>Chandan_Contactform_Model_Resource</class>
   <entities>
    <contactform>
     <table>contactform_contact_list/table>
    </contactform>
   </entities>
 </contactform_resource>
</models>
```

1. app/code/local/Chandan/Contactform/controllers/IndexController's indexAction() is like this ::

   $contact = Mage::getModel("contactform/contact");
   $contact->load($params['id']);
2. app/code/local/Chandan/Contactform/Model/Contact.php is like this ::

   class Chandan_Contactform_Model_Contact extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
   {
       protected function _construct()
       {
           $this->_init('contactform/contact');
       }

   }
3. However, it is giving me this error :
   Can't retrieve entity config: chandan_contactform/contact

What I am missing here? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to put, How can I put XML here? Not accepting the tags

Comment: please use  {} (code Sample of editor)

Comment: I have found out the solution :: The tag "<contactform>" immediately after "<entities>" tag should be changed to "<contact>". This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Your class name is `wrong` and also model  files path .

if you using `Mage::getModel("contactform/contact");`
then file structure
 should be

```
Chandan>Contactform>Model>Contact.php
Chandan>Contactform>Model>Resource>Contact.php
Chandan>Contactform>Model>Resource>Contact>Collection.php
```

Check [the link](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/)

Also issue in   is not closed.

```
  <class>Chandan_Contactform_Model_Resource/class>
```

to

```
<class>Chandan_Contactform_Model_Resource</class>
```

Comment: Dear Amit, I have maintaned the above file structure

Comment: Amit, that was a typo. In config.xml, everything is okay.